# Vaadin extension: MouseOverHandler

Tags: gwt, vaadin

In a simple extension I add a `VHorizontalLayout` with some `VLabel`. To the layout I add a `MouseOverHandler`, but its method is never invoked. What is wrong?

(Everything else works - i.e. the label is displayed below the extended field)

Connector:

```
@Connect(MyExtension.class)
public class MyExtensionConnector extends AbstractExtensionConnector {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyExtensionConnector.class.getName());


private final VHorizontalLayout layout = new VHorizontalLayout();

@Override
protected void extend(ServerConnector target) {
    LOG.info("-->extend");
    VLabel label = new VLabel();
    label.setText("some text");
    layout.add(label);

    final Widget field = ((ComponentConnector) target).getWidget();

    field.addAttachHandler(new AttachEvent.Handler() {
        @Override
        public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
            LOG.info("-->onAttachOrDetach: " + event.toDebugString());
            if (event.isAttached()) {
                field.getElement().getParentElement().insertAfter(layout.getElement(), field.getElement());
                layout.addHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
                        LOG.info("-->onMouseOver: " + event);
                    }
                }, MouseOverEvent.getType());
            } else {
                Element parentElement = layout.getElement().getParentElement();
                if (parentElement != null) {
                    parentElement.removeChild(layout.getElement());
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One should use `addDomHandler` instead of `addHandler`!